# remove mismatched rows in excel

Tags: excel

I am having an excel file with 2000 records containing few columns like

```
A           B              C             D              E
114         5              270           product1       118
117         3              150           product1       190
118         9              300           product2       114
190         6              110           product1
191         11             540           product3
```

what I want to do is I want to remove the rows that are not matching the column A with E.

```
Expected Output


     A           B              C             D        E         
    114         5              270        product1    114
    118         9              300        product2    118
    190         6              110        product1    190
```

Please help me

Comment: Without VBA, you could copy your values from column E into columns A and E of a new table (Expected Output), maybe sort them ascendingly. Then fill columns B,C,D with index/match or vlookup formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: your data table is in Sheet1, your Expected Output Table is in Sheet2.

Steps:

1. Copy column E of data table (DT) to column A of Expected Output Table (EOT).
2. Sort col A of EOT ascendingly (e.g. Data Ribbon > Sort & Filter).
3. Formula in B1 (EOT):

   ```
   =Index(Sheet1!B$1:B$5, Match(Sheet2!$A1, Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5, 0), 1)
   ```

Above formula goes into the columns B to D in EOT.

4. Formula in E1 (EOT):

   ```
   =$A1
   ```

The Index/Match would work even better if you had column headers. Then it would not matter whether the info from col B (DT) also goes into col B in EOT. Anyways, remember to adjust the ranges to your actual ones, and be careful with the $ signs.